# can't compile libfprint as a meson project

Tags: software-installation, compiling, fingerprint-reader

My ultimate goal: use the fingeprint reader of a Lenovo T430 on Ubuntustdio 20.04.

Type oft the device, according to `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode).
```

According to https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html they support this device.

I downloaded libfprint-master.tar.gz using the button Download from  https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint.git and unzipped it to some directory `libfprintf`. After unzipping, I find another directory `libfprint-master` in it and there is among others a directory `builddir` in that one.

After installing python and meson-0.61.1, I also added

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/verwalter/.local/bin"
```

to `~/.profile` in order to call meson builddir without explicitly giving the full path to meson. According to https://mesonbuild.com/Quick-guide.html#compiling-a-meson-project I should

1. `cd` to the root directory of the source code. I did so:

   ```
   cd /home/verwalter/Downloads/libfprint/libfprint-master
   ```
2. apply `meson builddir && cd builddir` from there
3. do further steps.

Step 2 failed with these messages:

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.61.1
Source dir: /home/verwalter/Downloads/libfprint/libfprint-master
Build dir: /home/verwalter/Downloads/libfprint/libfprint-master/builddir
Build type: native build
Project name: libfprint
Project version: 1.94.2
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.3.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0")
...
meson.build:68: WARNING: Consider using the built-in warning_level option instead of using "-Wall".
meson.build:69: WARNING: Consider using the built-in warning_level option instead of using "-Wall".
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
...
Run-time dependency gobject-2.0 found: YES 2.64.6
Did not find CMake 'cmake'
Found CMake: NO
Run-time dependency gusb found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

meson.build:84:0: ERROR: Dependency "gusb" not found, tried pkgconfig

A full log can be found at /home/verwalter/Downloads/libfprint/libfprint-master/builddir/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

What did I miss?
What's the next step to correct this?

Comment: `Dependency "gusb" not found`, run this `sudo apt-get install libgusb-dev`

Comment: What was wrong with official deb-package https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/libfprint ?

Comment: Liso, thank you for this advice. It helped me two steps further. Now I am stuck with ```meson.build:91:0: ERROR: Dependency "gobject-introspection-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig``` although I had issued ```sudo apt-get install gobject-introspection```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should know that this package is already available in [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/libfprint) with 1.90 version. So if you are not developer and do not want to patch the source code, then you can simply install the binaries by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfprint-2-2 libfprint-2-tod1
```

and then find a ways to test your fingerprint reader using this version of library.

---

If you need newer 1.94.1 version of fprintd on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you can proceed without compilation by adding [Zorin OS's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezorinos/+archive/ubuntu/fprint) by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zorinos/fprint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newer dependencies
```

---

If you are sure about the compilation - read below.
You have to start with getting build-dependencies of already packaged https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/libfprint package by following below steps:

1. Enable Source Code repositories (*deb-src*) in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Get build-dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get build-dep libfprint
   ```
3. Сompile libfprint 1.94.3 from Git again.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git cmake udev libudev-dev libgudev-1.0-dev
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://github.com/freedesktop/libfprint -b v1.94.3
   cd libfprint
   meson build
   meson test -C build --print-errorlogs
   sudo meson install -C build
   ```

Comment: I don't know if Zorin OS PPA turns Ubuntu into Zorin OS (Pop OS PPA and Kali repositories do so). It may be a good idea to install the specific package (instead of `dist-upgrade`) and remove the PPA afterwards.

Comment: I agree with your warning, but you can look into PPA contents and see 3 packages there, which are only frintd related. Having newer debhelper looks safe. Thanks :) Let's wait for the comments from OP.

Comment: I did not see the contents of the PPA before. It looks fine :)

Comment: I did the first steps until and including ```sudo apt-get install libfprint-2-2 libfprint-2-tod1```. If I understand you right, I need the other steps really only if i want to compile the newer version. Therefore I tried the fingerprint reader right away. I tried ```fprintd-enroll -f right-index-finger verwalter``` but I had to do ```sudo apt install fprintd``` first. Then I could enregister my fingerprint successfully. https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/fprint/#source-4 tells about tree packages, among them ```libfprint0```. But I can't find that one.

Comment: Followed the instructions above (on Jammy rather than Focal), but build is failing with a failure to find dependency "udev".  I've installed libudev-dev, which didn't fix it.  Any other ideas what's missing?